# access a getter from within a vue directive

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm writing a simple vue directive that returns true if a permission is matched with user permissions that are in the Vuex store. But I'm not able to access the state properly.

I'm able to access the getter `store.state.user.user.permissions` and also a getter `store.getters.currentUserPermissions` without any problem from within Vue components.

```
import store from './store/index';

Vue.directive('can',{
    inserted(el,binding){
        let permissions = store.getters.currentUserPermissions;

        console.log(permissions);
        if(!permissions.includes(binding.value)){
            el.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
});
```

the console returns `undefined`

But when I log `store.getters` in the console, I get:

```
{}
currentUserPermissions: (...)
> get currentUserPermissions: f ()
> __proto__: Object
```

How can I access currentUserPermissions?

Comment: Is this just a timing issue? Do you need to wait for the permissions to load before trying to show this page?

Comment: Well, when I click in de console on the `currentUserPermissions: (...)`, I can see the complete array of permissions, so I don't think it's a timing issue. Or do you have a better idea on how to check this?

Comment: The console shows a live copy. When you click on it you'll get the current value, not necessarily the value that was there when it was logged. Given you see `undefined` when logging the value itself it would suggest that it was there at that point. You could put some logging in your store to clarify exactly when the `state` is getting populated.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've just tried wrapping the code in a delay of 2 seconds, but it still gives the same result. So it doesn't seem to be timing related.

Answer (score 3):

I went through the same trouble and managed to find a solution. I'll leave it here to help others who may come looking for it.

The third argument of the directive argument, `vnode`, has access to the store through its `$context` property.
So the code would look like this:

```
Vue.directive('can',{
  inserted(el,binding,vnode){
    const store = vnode.context.$store;
    let permissions = store.getters.currentUserPermissions;

    console.log(permissions);
    if(!permissions.includes(binding.value)){
      el.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
});
```

Please notice that if the desired getter is inside a module, you would have to access it in a different way:

```
store.getters['<module>/<getter>']
```

Comment: Thanks man for sharing this, working on same feature and it's really helpful.